Linux kernel phantom reads
Why if i write to a raw hard disk (without FS) the kernel also makes reads.
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda   bs=32k   count=1 oflag=direct      status=none  

$ iostat -xc 1 /dev/sda | grep -E "Device|sda"
Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sda             45,54    0,99   1053,47     31,68     0,00     0,00   0,00   0,00    1,17 3071,00   3,04    23,13    32,00  66,38 308,91

Is it readahead?
Instead of dd i wrote a c program that does the same, i even used   posix_fadvise
to hint the kernel that i do not want read ahead.
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define BLOCKSIZE 512
#define COUNT  32768

int main(void)
{


// read COUNT bytes from /dev/zero

int fd;
mode_t mode = O_RDONLY;
char *filename = "/dev/zero";
fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, filename, mode);
if (fd < 0) {
      perror("Creation error");
      exit (1);
}



void *pbuf;
posix_memalign(&pbuf, BLOCKSIZE, COUNT);


size_t a;
a = COUNT;



ssize_t ret;
ret = read(fd, pbuf, a);
if (ret < 0) {
      perror("read  error");
      exit (1);
}


close (fd);


// write COUNT bytes to /dev/sda

int f = open("/dev/sda", O_WRONLY|__O_DIRECT);


ret = posix_fadvise (f, 0, COUNT, POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE);
if (ret < 0)
        perror ("posix_fadvise");


ret = write(f, pbuf, COUNT);
if (ret < 0) {
      perror("write  error");
      exit (1);
}

close(f);
free(pbuf);
return 0;



}

But the result is the same
 $ iostat -xc 1 /dev/sda | grep -E "Device|sda"

Device   r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sda    46,00    1,00   1064,00     32,00     10,78    1,00   0,43    23,13    32,00  10,55  49,60

It does not matter if it is a spindel  disk or ssd , the result is the same.
Also tried different kernels.

It could be actual reads, for example devices are scanned for new UUIDs, and if you dd a filesystem header instead of zeroes, it will magically appear in /dev/disk/by-uuid/...

I have found "the article"  that mentions phantom reads.  The article mentions the tools blktrace , blkparse .
I have launched dd and the tools.
sudo dd if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/sda  bs=4M  count=30   oflag=direct   status=progress  

sudo blktrace -d /dev/sda  -a read -o - | blkparse -i -  

It showed lots of rows with
  8,0    3        1 1266874889.708944253 25480  D   N 0 [systemd-udevd]
  8,0    1     1511     0.055573485 25510  I  RA 468861824 + 8 [(udev-worker)]  

So my assumption was - the reads were initiated by udev. After my write request to the raw disk was finished udev was checking if a new partition (or whatever) appeared,  to create new "/dev/N" file.
I temporarily disabled systemd-udevd  , relaunched dd write request and at that time "phantom" reads gone.
I started systemd-udevd back.  I launched long write  with dd.
"Phantom" reads appeared again but only at the very end. So definetely it is udev.
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    2.00   8192.00     0.00   0.00   10.50  4096.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.02   3.00

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00  109.00 446464.00     0.00   0.00    8.07  4096.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.88 100.00

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00  109.00 446464.00     0.00   0.00    8.04  4096.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.88 100.40

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda            267.00   1068.00     0.00   0.00    0.07     4.00   80.00 327680.00     0.00   0.00    8.03  4096.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.66  76.00
 
 

I think it makes  sense.  When the disk stops processing writes from a user process udev checks if a new partition\fs appears on it
